# Connection error with Relay

Tags: relayjs, graphql-js

```js
// didn't add node definitions because this problem occurs on initial data fetch

// user type
const userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
      id: globalIdField('User'),
      email: { type: GraphQLString },
      posts: {
        type: postConnection,
        args: connectionArgs,
        // getUserPosts() function is below
        resolve: (user, args) => connectionFromArray(getUserPosts(user.id), args),
      },
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
})

// post type
const postType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Post',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('Post'),
    title: { type: GraphQLString },
    content: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
})  

// connection type
const {connectionType: postConnection} =
  connectionDefinitions({name: 'Post', nodeType: postType})
```

---

```js
// Mongoose query on other file
exports.getUserPosts = (userid) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Post.find({'author': userid}).exec((err, res) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(res)
    })
  })
}
```

---

I get the following warning in browser console:

> Server request for query `App` failed for the following reasons:
>
> 1. Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
>    _posts40BFVD:posts(first:10) {
>
>    ^^^

---

That's the only information I got, there's no more errors or references. What could be the reason?

This code is from [relay-starter-kit](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-starter-kit), I only replaced all the `Widget` code with `Post`. Everything is almost the same as in starter, therefore I think the cause is somewhere around the database code.

But I can't see the problem because `getUserPosts()` returns same structure: array of objects..

---

### What was the problem?

```js
resolve: (user, args) => connectionFromArray(getUserPosts(user.id), args)
```

`getUserPosts()` returned a promise (blocking code would probably be a bad idea) but there was no callback. What happened in my opinion was that `connectionFromArray()` continued executing the code but it didn't have the data from `getUserPosts()` yet, which caused the whole system to fail.

### One possible solution

I use Babel and JavaScript "future features" anyway, therefore I decided to use `async` and `await`. But there still was a problem and `getUserPosts()` returned an empty array.

Then I discovered that if another function is called with `await` in a `async` function, that another function has to be `async` as well, otherwise all `await-s` fail. Here's my final solution that works:

```js
// async function that makes db query
exports.getUserPosts = async (userId) => {
    try {
      // db query
      const posts = await Post.find({author: args}).exec()
      return posts
    } catch (err) {
      return err
    }
}

// and resolve method in Schema, also async
resolve: async (user, args) => {
  const posts = await getUserPosts(user._id)
  return connectionFromArray(posts, args)
}
```

Im not still sure though if it's the best way. My logic tells me that I should use async as much as possible in Node but Im far from Node expert. I'll update the question when I know more about it.

**I would be glad to know if there's a better or even a recommended way to deal with this database query situation using Relay.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

graphql-relay provides a [connectionFromPromisedArray](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/master/src/connection/arrayconnection.js#L50) function which waits until the promise resolves. `resolve: (user, args) => connectionFromPromisedArray(getUserPosts(user.id), args),` which probably is the most recommended/easiest way when dealing with promised connections.

If your `user.id` is a [global ID](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-object-identification.html#content) field then you have to extract the real DB ID from the base64 string `const { type, id } = fromGlobalId(user.id);`.
or
`resolve: (user, args) => connectionFromPromisedArray(getUserPosts(fromGlobalId(user.id).id), args),`

In a app I work on which is using Relay and Mongoose I found it better to write my own connection implementation to handle pagination and filtering on the DB level rather than on the app level. I took a lot of inspiration from [graffiti-mongoose](https://github.com/RisingStack/graffiti-mongoose/blob/master/src/query/query.js#L266-L321) when I wrote it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the `resolve` function of `posts` field.

```
resolve: (user, args) => connectionFromArray(getUserPosts(user.id), args),
```

First, `getUserPosts` is an asynchronous function which returns a promise. You have to take that into account while writing `resolve` function. Second, `user.id` is a global ID field generated for you by `graphql-relay` module's `globalIdField` helper function. That ID should be converted to local ID.

With relay-starter-kit, you [can use](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-starter-kit/blob/f9a66f75cc77f095d189b9efd17f8409c585d663/.babelrc#L11) `async` and `await`. The code will look like:

```
resolve: async (user, args) => {
  let userId = fromGlobalId(user.id).id;
  // convert this userId string to Mongo ID if needed
  // userId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId).
  const posts = await getUserPosts(userId);
  return connectionFromArray(posts, args),
},
```

---

In your `async` version of `getUserPosts`, the `err` object is returned in case of error.

```
exports.getUserPosts = async (userId) => {
  try {
    // db query
    const posts = await Post.find({author: args}).exec()
    return posts
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}
```

A good practice is to either re-throw the error or return an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand it. This relatively short answer was very eye-opening. That somewhat solved the issue but now `getUserPosts` returns an empty array for some reason and `edges` is empty array too. I used `console.log` right after the `await` line. Any ideas?

Comment: **I figured it out! :-)** `async` and `await` only works when the functions you wait on (`getUserPosts ` in my example) is also `async`.. Thank you for your effort! You pointed me to right direction. I guess `async` is the way to go with Node, don't you think? I'll update the question.

Comment: Forgot to add Relay global ID to local ID translation part. Revised the answer. Please check and let us know.

Comment: @Solo, you can use `try ... catch` blocks to handle errors in `async` functions. You will find many async await examples with error handling on the Internet. By the way, if you return Promise in an asynchronous function, you do not need to put `async` in that function's declaration.